# Event.preventDefault() not working, form submitted twice

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two pages, both forms are basically the same, with the stripe element, but one has extra fields and the other does not.

The form with extra fields `event.preventDefault()` does not seem to stop the form submit, so the form gets submitted twice, but one without extra fields does not.

#### Why is one form `isTrusted === true` and the other `isTrusted === false`?  What controls this?

Could this be the cause of the `preventDefault()` not working?

After more testing, I found that:

```
<%= form_tag add_card_path(@product.id), id: "payment-form" do
```

does not submit twice, but

```
<%= form_with add_card_path(@product.id), id: "payment-form" do
```

does submit twice, hence the `preventDefault()` does not work.

Why would that be?

```
<%= form_tag add_card_path(@product.id), id: "payment-form" do %>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert" class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div id="card-element" class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row mt-3">
    <button class="btn_spinner col btn md-width-auto btn-primary">Add Card</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Javascript:

```
// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById(thatInstance.formId);
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  debugger;
  thatInstance.createStripeToken();
});
```

Inspecting Event Object from Debugger:

### Working Page:

Event Object:

```
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
composed: false
currentTarget: <form id="payment-form">
defaultPrevented: true
eventPhase: 2
isTrusted: false
returnValue: false
srcElement: <form id="payment-form">
target: <form id="payment-form">
timeStamp: 20826
type: "submit"
```

### Non Working Page:

Event Object:

```
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
composed: false
currentTarget: <form id="payment-form">
defaultPrevented: true
eventPhase: 2
isTrusted: true
returnValue: false
srcElement: <form id="payment-form">
target: <form id="payment-form">
timeStamp: 23652
type: "submit"
```

### Solution:

Needed `data-remote === false`, not sure why.

Form_with has `data-remote === true`, while form_tag has `data-remote === false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails form_with() and form_tag() operate differently.

According to this article:

https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a

"All forms generated by form_with will be submitted by an XHR (Ajax) request by default. There is no need to specify remote: true as you have to with form_tag and form_for."

Hence, either turning remote to false (local: true) or using form_tag solved the issue, as .preventDefault stops the local submit, not ajax submits.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) about [`Event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted):

> The **`isTrusted`** read-only property of the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface is a [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) that is `true` when the event was generated by a user action, and `false` when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) about [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> Calling **`preventDefault()`** for a non-cancelable event, such as one dispatched via [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), without specifying `cancelable: true`  has no effect.

Comment: I had googled that, but I don't understand why the same script, on 2 different pages would act differently.

Comment: @user2012677 do you dispatch an event in the second case?

Comment: The JS is the exact same, and the forms get submitted the exact same.

Comment: @user2012677 seems like not the same. Could you create a code snippet with the problem?

Comment: @user2012677 you should post the answer and accept it then.